# File protocol support for VideoView or WebView?

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, android-videoview

In Google Chrome browser on my Desktop computer I am able to stream an mp4 video file residing on my server using the following link:

```
file://192.168.0.1/Videos/video.mp4
```

I would like to do the same in an Android app but when I tried to place this same link into a VideoView or WebView it would encounter an error.

In VideoView it would give an error saying it cannot play this file and in WebView it give a file permission error.

VideoView code I am using is:

```
    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;

    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL = "file://192.168.0.1/Videos/video.mp4";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

WebView code is:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadUrl("file://192.168.0.1/Videos/video.mp4");
```

Is the format of the links for the file protocols different in VideoView or WebView causing this to not work or is it a different issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using a Windows or Linux machine as a server. You'll have to implement a Android supported video streaming format if you want VideoView to work.

Just to make clear the `file://` URI scheme doesn't specify a network protocol and 'SMB/CIFS' which Windows natively and Linux with SAMBA server uses for file sharing isn't native to Android.

From: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-kerwin-file-scheme-07.html#rfc.section.3.4

The last paragraph is what is important:

> The 'file' URI scheme is unusual in that it does not specify an
>   Internet protocol or access method for shared files; as such, its
>   utility in network protocols between hosts is limited. Examples of
>   file server protocols that do define such access methods include
>   SMB/CIFS [MS-SMB2], NFS [RFC3530], and NCP [NOVELL].

For a workable solution: I recommend searching for http/https video streaming for your server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into http/https video streaming for my Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

The video should be in android supported format. You can find the supported video format [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html).

Also `file://` is not an URL, it indicates file system. You have to provide an URL which will start with `http` or `https`.

As you are using your computer as server, make sure your android device and your computer are in the same network. Otherwise your video will not be found by the android device.